# Deleteing a repository in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

where can I find .git folder to delete a repo on my system. I opened my local disk as a repository and I have about 5k changes to make.The thing is if I check my git account my local disk is not showing as a repo so i really dont know what is going on. Any solution will be welcomed.

Comment: search from the current workspace directory or project directory up the directory tree and find the .git, easiest to do in a terminal or you need to show hidden files. in git-bash use `ls -a`

Comment: The ls-a didn't work but when I found it when I enabled hidden files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the "5k changes", select a file and open it in your file browser. Enable hidden files/folders. Start moving up the hierarchy of that path, i.e., keeping going up in the parent directory of the file.

You'll find the .git folder somewhere. Check its creation date. If it's recent, delete it. Be careful not to delete any commits you had made in some project.

Comment: Thank you. I found the .git folder when I enabled the hidden item/folders. It's crazy how something so minute can cause such big problems.